# Ubuntu 18.04 with dnsmasq causing dns leaks

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, ubuntu-18.04, strongswan, resolv.conf

This problem is making me tear out my hair, as I simply cannot believe dnsmasq can work in this fashion by default.

It is absolutely preposterous

ok so dnsmasq is installed 2.79-1

And server is being used as a VPN server with strongswan and ipsec being used.

/etc/dnsmasq.conf:

```
bind-interfaces
interface=eth0
cache-size=500
no-negcache
no-hosts
domain-needed
resolv-file=/etc/resolv.dnsmasq
no-poll
```

/etc/resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

/etc/resolv.dnsmasq:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Now I am able to do DNS queries

BUT

Queries get forwarded to 8.8.8.8.  So 8.8.8.8 sees the client IP not the server IP

This creates DNS leaks and this makes the VPN server essentially useless.

How can this be standard config and how do I fix this so the server NAT's the DNS queries and the client IP is always protected?

**EDIT**

Another solution would be to specify the dns server in strongswan config but as far as I've read strongswan doesnt allow dynamic ip's in the rightdns property so a IP needs to be spesified which is why it's currently set to the public IP of the VPN server.  Or if I could set the VPN server IP on the ipsec interface; for instance 10.10.10.254.

Maybe there is an easy way to do this???

Comment: Why nameservers do the clients this k they are using?

Comment: Im sorry dude, I don't speak that language...

Comment: What client are you using? Are you using IKEv2, or IKEv1? Is L2TP involved?

Comment: I tried several clients, I'm trying to stay with the built-in features as much as possible so built in windows client, gnome network manager and plugins and StrongSwan on android.

Comment: IKEv2 exclusively; no L2TP

Comment: But I got completely fed up with trying to force dnsmasq to do something it should be doing by default, and switched to unbound.  That did the trick with almost no config needed and I got the DNSSEC working with no DNS leaks with ease.  Honestly unbound felt much more natural to setup and how it functions.  Even the configs make more sense